# Why can't I remove the event listeners?

Tags: javascript, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I've reviewed many answers to similar questions, but I don't have a solution.

The if statements below ensure that the listeners are only added once, and as I resize the window I can see the attributes added and removed accordingly. Unfortunately, I'm finding the listeners are not removed. For the throttle, I'm using [this function](https://gist.github.com/prevostc/dcb395fc8ae4cf094e42d262e77746bd).

Why can't I remove the listeners?

```
window.addEventListener('load', loadListenersHome);
window.addEventListener('resize', throttle(loadListenersHome(), 1000));

function loadListenersHome() {

  var navPanel = document.getElementById('nav');
  var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');

  var makeNavPanelOpaque = function() {
    if (navPanel.className.indexOf('change') !== -1) {
      navPanel.setAttribute('style','background-color: white;');
    }
  }
  var makeNavPanelTransparent = function() {
    if (navPanel.className.indexOf('change') !== -1) {
      navPanel.setAttribute('style','');
    }
  }

  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 567.98px)').matches && window.matchMedia('(max-height: 799.98px)').matches) {
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseenter') !== 'added') {
      trigger.addEventListener('mouseenter', makeNavPanelOpaque, false);
      trigger.setAttribute('listener-mouseenter','added');
    }
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseleave') !== 'added') {
      trigger.addEventListener('mouseleave', makeNavPanelTransparent, false);
      trigger.setAttribute('listener-mouseleave','added');
    }
  } else {
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseenter') === 'added') {
      trigger.removeEventListener('mouseenter', makeNavPanelOpaque, false);
      trigger.removeAttribute('listener-mouseenter');
    }
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseleave') === 'added') {
      trigger.removeEventListener('mouseleave', makeNavPanelTransparent, false);
      trigger.removeAttribute('listener-mouseleave');
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE 1 (this works, but is not throttled):

```
window.addEventListener('load', addRemoveListeners);
window.addEventListener('resize', addRemoveListeners);

function addRemoveListeners() {
  var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 567.98px)').matches && window.matchMedia('(max-height: 799.98px)').matches) {
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseenter') !== 'added') {
      addListener(trigger, 'mouseenter', makeNavPanelOpaque, false);
      trigger.setAttribute('listener-mouseenter','added');
    }
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseleave') !== 'added') {
      addListener(trigger, 'mouseleave', makeNavPanelTransparent, false);
      trigger.setAttribute('listener-mouseleave','added');
    }
  } else {
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseenter') === 'added') {
      removeListener(trigger, 'mouseenter', makeNavPanelOpaque, false);
      trigger.removeAttribute('listener-mouseenter');
    }
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseleave') === 'added') {
      removeListener(trigger, 'mouseleave', makeNavPanelTransparent, false);
      trigger.removeAttribute('listener-mouseleave');
    }
  }
}

function makeNavPanelOpaque() {
  var navPanel = document.getElementById('nav');
  if (navPanel.className.indexOf('change') !== -1) {
    navPanel.setAttribute('style','background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.96); height: 100%;');
  }
}

function makeNavPanelTransparent() {
  var navPanel = document.getElementById('nav');
  if (navPanel.className.indexOf('change') !== -1) {
    navPanel.setAttribute('style','');
  }
}
```

UPDATE 2 (for Peter, listeners are not added on resize with this version):

```
window.addEventListener('load', addRemoveListeners);
window.addEventListener('resize', throttleAddRemoveListeners);

var throttleAddRemoveListeners = throttle(addRemoveListeners, 1000);

function addRemoveListeners() {
  var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 567.98px)').matches && window.matchMedia('(max-height: 799.98px)').matches) {
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseenter') !== 'added') {
      addListener(trigger, 'mouseenter', makeNavPanelOpaque, false);
      trigger.setAttribute('listener-mouseenter','added');
    }
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseleave') !== 'added') {
      addListener(trigger, 'mouseleave', makeNavPanelTransparent, false);
      trigger.setAttribute('listener-mouseleave','added');
    }
  } else {
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseenter') === 'added') {
      removeListener(trigger, 'mouseenter', makeNavPanelOpaque, false);
      trigger.removeAttribute('listener-mouseenter');
    }
    if(trigger.getAttribute('listener-mouseleave') === 'added') {
      removeListener(trigger, 'mouseleave', makeNavPanelTransparent, false);
      trigger.removeAttribute('listener-mouseleave');
    }
  }
}

function makeNavPanelOpaque() {
  var navPanel = document.getElementById('nav');
  if (navPanel.className.indexOf('change') !== -1) {
    navPanel.setAttribute('style','background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.96); height: 100%;');
  }
}

function makeNavPanelTransparent() {
  var navPanel = document.getElementById('nav');
  if (navPanel.className.indexOf('change') !== -1) {
    navPanel.setAttribute('style','');
  }
}
```

Comment: `throttle()` expects a function reference as its first argument. You pass it `undefined` (therefor there should be an error in the console)

Comment: Just a guess: with `var`, `makeNavPanelOpaque` and `makeNavPanelTransparent` are scoped to `loadListenersHome`, this means that each time you call that function a new variable is produced and the reference doesn't match the one you initially passed to `addEventListener`. You could try to declare those two variables globally.

Comment: Two mistakes, `throttle` creates a throttled version of a function/method, thus the OP needs to pass the reference of a to be throttled function instead of invoking it. And `removeEventListener` needs the reference of the very handler which was passed to `addEventListener`, thus the OP needs to assign the throttled version of said function/method to a variable and use this variable/reference for both registering and unregistering the throttled handler ... e.g. `const handler = throttle(loadListenersHome, 1000); ...addEventListener('resize', handler); ...removeEventListener('resize', handler);`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. To get this working removed throttle and pulled the ```make``` functions out into their own scope. I haven't figured out how to implement @PeterSeliger's suggestion without polluting the global namespace, but I'm curious. Anyway, things are working now with the updated code so I'm happy. Much appreciated!!

Comment: @chillywilly ... since the OP already _"pollutes"_ the global namespace with all the function statements including `loadListenersHome` it shouldn't be a problem to create and assign a throttled version of this function there as well. On the other hand, the OP's code should be executed within the projects own module(s) scope anyway.

Comment: @PeterSeliger - Again, thank you very much for your reply. I just have a habit of avoiding global variables, but if I understand correctly you're only suggesting one so I'm willing to try this. Unfortunately I haven't figured out the correct syntax to make this work. I've pasted my latest attempt above (Update 2). Without throttle everything seems to be work (Update 1), so I could just leave it there and all seems well. I'm just interested in learning how to implement your suggestion if you feel like talking about it more. If not, I understand.